# How do I call an implementation of hook_form_alter()?

Tags: forms

I have a function in my module that implements hook_form_alter(): `function getuserform_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)`.

How do I call it? How do I pass it the required parameters?

Comment: that is - hook_form_alter(). typing too fast...

Comment: I have figured it out.  the hook_alter_form gets called automatically when any form is called. So I just have to retrieve the modified form using drupal_get_form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_form_alter` comes in two variants:

- `hook_form_alter`
- `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`

Both are called when a form is retrieved using `drupal_get_form` or one of the other form builder functions, but the latter is only invoked for the form with the specific form_id. Unless you are doing the same alterations to multiple forms, it's a good idea to use the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` variation, as it will create less overhead.

All hooks are called by Drupal when certain events happen. For `form_alter`, that is when the form is being built. So all you need to do, using the example in your question, is to do a check on the `$form_id` and do the alterations you want.

Notice `$form_state` should be passed by reference using the `&$form_state` notation. Sometimes you need to not only change `$form` but also `$form_state` to be able to modify the form like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Like other hook implementations, they are automatically called by Drupal core code.

You don't invoke an implementation of `hook_form_alter()` (or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`), in the same way you don't directly call an implementation of `hook_user()` (or `hook_user_OP()`, in Drupal 7). You call a Drupal function that invokes that type of hooks: for `hook_user()`, you call `user_load()`; for `hook_nodeapi()`, you call `node_load()`; for `hook_form_alter()`, you call `drupal_get_form()`, `drupal_build_form()`, or `ajax_get_form()`.